# Keep formulas referencing original column name from table after adding column to table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-tables

In excel have a table named "MyTable" with two columns:

| NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 2020.01.01 |
| Jane | 2021.02.15 |

I have a formula to find the max value of the "DATE" column "=MAX(MyTable[Date])" which returns "2021.02.15"

I need to update "MyTable" with new data, but it has additional columns and the columns aren't in the same order:

| NAME | Dollars | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 500 | 2020.01.01 |
| Jane | 250 | 2021.02.15 |

If I paste the new data with the additional column into "MyTable" my max date formula automatically updates to "=MAX(MyTable[Dollars])" which now returns "500" not "2021.02.15"

Is there a way to replace the data in the table with data that contains additional columns and columns in a different order without having every formula in the workbook shift it's column reference to an incorrect column? (in the actual problem I'm trying to solve, the source data is from a government website so I don't control the source formatting, which changes frequently. And there are 275+ columns so it's not feasible to manually rearrange the table every time there is a change)

Comment: I would use match() to find each column  heading and index() from there.

Comment: Would this work? `=MAX(MyTable[[Date]:[Date]])` referencing the from:to ranges makes it behave as locked when dragging your formula to a different column. I'm unable to reproduce your error though.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("MyTable[Date]"))
```

The use of `INDIRECT` lets me hard-code the reference as a text value so it won’t dynamically update if the column order in the table is changed.